# The SQ argument in Balazs Szorenyi's paper

Tags: ds.algorithms, lower-bounds, query-complexity, stochastic-process

I am asking about the proof in Theorem 5 (page 6) of this paper,
[http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/~szorenyi/Cikkek/sq_d0_ext.pdf](http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/%7Eszorenyi/Cikkek/sq_d0_ext.pdf)

Quite a few things about this short argument seem unclear to me,

- Towards the bottom of page 3 when the SQ oracle was defined it seemed that for a tolerance parameter of $\tau$ and the true concept being $f^*$ and a query concept of $h$ the SQ oracle is guaranteed to return a $c$ s.t $\vert c - \langle f^*,h \rangle \vert \leq \tau$. Now in the proof of Theorem 5 (page 6) there is no $f^*$ that has been mentioned! So is there an implicit assumption about what this $f^*$ is?

  Are we assuming that this $f^*$ is a part of this uncorrelated set, $\{f_1,f_2,..,f_d\}$?
- The argument in Theorem 5 seems to assume that the adversarial oracle can return $c=0$ always. But why should this be a consistent option given that the oracle is forced to satisfy the condition, $\vert c - \langle f^*,h \rangle \vert \leq \tau$. If $c=0$ has to always be a consistent oracle reply then we need it to be true that all queries $h$ being made are such that it satisfies the equation, $\vert\langle f^*,h \rangle \vert \leq \tau$. But now this is a new constraint that the queries $h$ have to be of somewhat low correlation with the truth $f^*$!. But this wasnt specified anywhere!

  At this point it seems that the algorithm could be lucky and it could send to the Oracle the query $h = f^*$ and then if $c=0$ has to be a valid adversarial reply we need $\tau \geq 1$ and that doesnt make sense!
- Lastly what else is the SQ algorithm allowed to do apart from making $(h,\tau)$ SQ-queries? Are we forcing it to work s.t after it receives $c=0$ as the Oracle reply all its allowed to do is to eliminate from its set of probable outputs those functions in the set $\{f_1,..,f_d\}$ which are more than $\tau$ correlated? Why is it that the SQ algorithm never seems to consider that there could be functions in ${\cal F}$ outside this uncorrelated set which are also more than $\tau$ correlated to the query $h$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a standard adversary argument, not very different from adversary arguments taught in undergraduate algorithms courses. If you are unfamiliar with such arguments, then you can check out [these notes](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/13-adversary.pdf) by Jeff Erickson.

The idea for the proof is that the SQ oracle is controlled by an adversary, and the adversary does not have to initially commit to a specific $f^*$. Instead, the adversary always makes sure that *some* $f^*$ is consistent with the oracle answers. In Szorenyi's paper, the adversary will make sure that there is always some $f_i$ which is consistent with all of the query answers. More precisely, let $\cal G$ be the set of all $f_i$ which are consistent with answering $0$ to all queries so far. If no queries have been answered yet, then $\mathcal{G} = \{f_1, \ldots, f_d\}$. Szorenyi shows that answering a new query by $0$ decreases $|\cal G|$ by at most $2d/(d\tau^2 - 1)$, so as long as $|\mathcal{G}| > 2d / (d\tau^2-1)$, the adversary can keep answering queries by $0$ and $\cal G$ will remain non-empty. Moreover, while this is true, the algorithm cannot stop and output an answer, because any possible concept it outputs will have correlation less than $\tau$ with $|\mathcal{G}| - d / (d\tau^2-1)> 0$ many concepts in $\mathcal{G}$. But any concept in $\mathcal{G}$ could be $f^*$, and the algorithm would output the wrong answer for at least one such possible $f^*$.

Another way to see the last point is the following. Suppose that the algorithm outputs something while $|\mathcal{G}| > 2d / (d\tau^2-1)$. Then take an element of $\cal G$ that has correlation less than $\tau$ with the algorithm's output, and call it $f^*$. Rerun the whole process again with the oracle always outputting $0$: all the oracle answers are consistent with $f^*$ (by the construction of $\cal G$) and the algorithm would produce the same output, but that output would be incorrect for $f^*$. Note that this assumes that the algorithm is deterministic.

One detail he doesn't mention is that once $|\mathcal{G}| \le 2d / (d\tau^2-1)$, the adversary can pick some $f^* \in \mathcal{G}$ and answer new queries in any way consistent with $f^*$. This doesn't matter much in the proof because it can only happen once $(d\tau^2 - 1)/2$ queries have been made.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this looks like an odd argument style to me because I am not from a traditional CS background! So here it seems that you are letting the adversary choose the $f^*$ after it has seen all the queries sent by the algorithm. But isnt that violating the premise of what a learning algorithm is? Isnt it just a part of the definition of the SQ oracle that it knows/commits to a $f^*$ from the beginning and gives noisy values of its inner-product with the query sent? Isnt it unfair to the learner if you let the oracle choose $f^*$ after seeing all the queries?

Comment: It's just a way to identify the worst-case $f^*$ (and worst-case query answers consistent with $f^*$) for every learner by playing a game with the learner. In the game, the adversary controls the oracle. The game is "fair" because at the end of it, the adversary must be able to reveal some $f^*$ consistent with *all* its query answers. Because of this, if the oracle had committed to this $f^*$ from the beginning, the algorithm would've made the exact same queries and gotten the exact same answers.